# excel add new data and push down old data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a spreadsheet for employees at my company to add their in and out times.  I already have the formulas that will show all the days of the current week.  The employee enters the time for that week.  When the next week comes the data will change and the old times are deleted.  Now I was wondering if there is away to use formulas to copy the times entered into another sheet in the same book.  The catch is it would have to be added to the data from last week (and the week before etc) that would be already there instead of writing over it.

This would be easy in VBA but I would like to see if there is a way to do it with formulas before I start writing macros.

Comment: One of the problems that i see with trying to do this with formulas is that your date ranges are dynamic.  With dates changing each week any linked formulas will also change. Even if you took the time intensive job of writing a specific formula specific to each day of week when the base file changes the values would revert to a #REF error.  I would recommend researching VBA code for copy and paste to your desired location.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this with formulae only because a formula does not store data.